# Understanding non-static class member access

Tags: c++, class

I'd like to understand all case allowing us using of the `::` operator to get  access class data members. For instance, we could use `::` to access static data members. Actually,

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    static const int b = 3;
};

int main() { std::cout << A::b << std::endl; }
```

also, we could use the expression to get access to non-static data members within a `brace-or-equal initializer` of a non-static data member.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int b = 3;
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << A::b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() { A().foo(); }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/310f74d2a20854bb)**

I'm looking for the rule covering all cases where we could use `::` operator. What chapter of the Strandard tells us that we should't use `::` to accessing non-static data member like this

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int b = 3;
};

int main() { std::cout << A::b << std:endl; } //error
```

Comment: It's called the scope resolution operator. It's covered throughout the standard and can be used in several ways. I don't think they're enumerated in a single place.

Comment: I don't think a quote from the standard is the most helpful way of explaining why the last example won't work. I think a basic explanation of the scope resolution operator and non-static data members would be more appropriate.

Comment: the last example doesn't make sense.  how does it know which instance to get the b from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.1.1.13 in the C++14 standard:

> An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static
>   member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - as part of a class member access (5.2.5) in which the object expression refers to the member’s class or a class derived from that
>     class, or
> - to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), or
> - if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.

Case 1 is where you are trying to be more specific about what member you mean.  For example `a.A::b`.

Case 2 is where you take the address of the member.  For example `&A::b`.

Case 3 is where it is unevaluated.  For example `sizeof(A::b)`.

The `A::b` in your example is none of these, so it is illegal.

Comment: Maybe we should add that this is used to resolve ambiguities with multiple inheritance.